# Can not connect to sql database on azure from behind the proxy server in sql management studio?

Tags: sql-server, azure, proxy

Recently i had deployed a website on Microsoft azure platform. I had configured SQL database on azure. I am working behind proxy server so i had registered my proxy server IP address to the Azure portal where i had enabled SQL server access to true and inserted my IP address so azure can allow me to access.

In my proxy server, i had pointed out SQL server name (given from azure) to one of local IP address for using it locally. When i had tried to connect with username and password provided by azure. I got following error message as find an image in attachment.

[image: SQL Error]

It has been displayed as a connection was successfully established but during pre-login handshake, an error is occurred that existing connection has been forcibly closed by the remote host. As i had registered my IP address in SQL azure portal for access.

Please suggest me a better way of it. As i am using free trial of azure right now so i could not generate any support ticket ticket right now.

Comment: OP .. did you make any config changes in your SSMS to use your corp proxy server ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems common if you are using the organizational network.Even if azure is getting your IP but still it does get changed when traffic flows through org network.Try to use global Ip address i.e; startIpaddress 0.0.0.0 EndIPAddress 255.255.255.255.

Comment: While this may work, allowing access from any address is usually not advised.

Comment: What will be the convenience way to accomplish this?
I am running out of time and i need solution urgently.

Comment: we had tried this way but it is also not working. Also this solution is not reliable as we can not state global ip addresses in this way.